# Why is it recommended to install Jupyter via Anaconda?

Tags: pip, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

In the Jupyter installation page, [they said](http://jupyter.org/install):

> We strongly recommend installing Python and Jupyter using the Anaconda Distribution

My question is **why** ?

Does the installation using **pip** implies issues ?

Comment: If you read that sentence till the end, I think you'll have your answer. It says "... *which includes Python, the Jupyter Notebook, and other commonly used packages for scientific computing and data science*". Personally as a beginner myself in Python, I find following anaconda simpler and easier

Comment: Is that the only reason ? The recommendation is so much strong so you may think that there is another reason...

Comment: I was hoping for a better reason.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda packages include non python dependencies but if you use pip you should resolve dependency problems with system packages (more steps and mix package sources/managers manually).

Below, a comparative table from [Anaconda site](https://www.anaconda.com/understanding-conda-and-pip/):

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what you have in parentheses. Do you mean that there are more steps if you use `pip` and thus that's the downside or did you mean that pip will resolv those dependencies for you by mixing the package sources?

Comment: @heretoinfinityyes, there are more steps that you need to do (not pip for you, "you should resolve dependency problems with system packages" or in WIndows, download, compile, etc...).